# Malihu jQuery Custom Scrollbar with Meteor doesn't show up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, meteor

I've got Malihu's custom scrollbar added to my meteor app this one: http://atmospherejs.com/mrt/malihu-custom-scrollbar

I've got this code:

```
Template.post.rendered = function() {

    $('body').mCustomScrollbar({
        theme: 'minimal-dark'
    });

}
```

and I see that it's added the right classes to the `body` however, I don't see the custom scroll bar, instead I see the normal scroll bar.

What am I missing? Is there something specific I need to do?

By the way I am using `Meteor v0.9.0`

Comment: I just tried and got the same result. It looks like the package is not being maintained so someone else will need to create a version compatible with the new packaging system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed this myself and ended up writing a quick package to make it compatible with `Meteor v0.9.0.1`

You can find it here: http://atmospherejs.com/maazalik/malihu-jquery-custom-scrollbar

I tested it on some elements and it worked fine.